# Strange issue with DNS: drill works but getent hosts does not

Tags: linux, arch-linux, dns, etc, resolv.conf

I'm running Arch Linux ARM on a Raspberry Pi 4. I'm currently having an issue with the domain resolution. The "user space" applications including ping, web browser, etc. do not resolve hosts, although I can, for example, access https://1.1.1.1 in Chromium. drill works normally (?!), but `getent hosts` does not. I've tried overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf` and using `resolvconf -u` (with editing `/etc/resolvconf.conf`) to no avail. Any ideas? (`/etc/hosts` works as expected)

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
domain lan
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

```
$ drill unix.stackexchange.org
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY:, rcode: NXDOMAIN, id: 45971
;; flags qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;; unix.stackexchange.org.    IN       A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
unix.stackexchange.org. 14400   IN    CNAME    stackexchange.org.
stackexchange.org.      14400   IN    A        67.227.226.240

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:

;; Query time: 111 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.42.129
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 26 13:09:11 2019
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 70
```

```
$ grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts: files mymachines myhostname resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the non-comment content of `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Added resolv.conf to the question

Comment: Yes, "command not found." Can I use drill or something similar?

Comment: OK, I did have to hand-copy it though so hopefully no mistakes

Comment: OK, that's done too

Comment: My guess is something in `nsswitch.conf` is the problem, but I don't know what `mymachines` `myhostname` or `resolve` do on Arch.  You could try making that line read `hosts: files dns` and see if that helps, but without knowing what the others are for, I can't say with any authority that that's the right thing to do.

Comment: That worked. I wish I understood why.

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers may use DNS-over-HTTPS ([Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/developers/dns-over-https), [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https)). As a result, they may have functioning hostname resolution that is totally independent of the main OS.

Your `nsswitch.conf` specifies that `resolve` (i.e. `systemd-resolved`) is to be tried first before traditional `resolv.conf`-based DNS lookups (`dns`). If the `systemd-resolved` cannot find the requested data, or it reports a temporary error code, the failure will taken as the result of the lookup. You can view the DNS servers used by `systemd-resolved` by running `resolvectl status`.

The `drill` command explicitly looks into `resolv.conf` for default nameservers; other than that, it skips the `nsswitch.conf` mechanisms entirely and does all the work by itself.

(`systemd-resolved` explicitly ignores `resolv.conf` to allow programs like `drill` to be redirected to `systemd-resolved` by specifying `nameserver 127.0.0.53` in `resolv.conf`, and also because `systemd-resolved` allows the configuration of different DNS servers for different network interfaces.)

So, my interpretation of what is happening is this:

- Chromium: works because it's using DNS-over-HTTPS.
- `drill`: works because it skips `nsswitch.conf` and just looks at `resolv.conf` directly.
- basically everything else: uses mechanisms specified in `nsswitch.conf` and ends up querying `systemd-resolved` which apparently has non-functional DNS settings for some reason (maybe its requests get blocked by firewalls, or it is talking to an uncooperative DNS server?), and so fails to get DNS information. The DNS servers specified in `resolv.conf` would get used by this class of programs only if attempts to use `systemd-resolved` returned a "permanent failure" result code - and apparently that is not happening right now.

`mymachines` in `nsswitch.conf` probably refers to [this hostname resolution module](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-mymachines.html) that will automatically resolve the hostnames of local virtual machines and other containers managed by `systemd-machined`. It should have no effect whatsoever in resolving non-local names.

Likewise, `myhostname` probably refers to [this hostname resolution module](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-myhostname.html) which ensures that the current local hostname, the names `localhost` and `localhost.localdomain` and the name `_gateway` will always get resolved, even if no network connectivity exists.

Comment: The example given in Chromium uses an https URL with an IP address so there is no name to resolve.